# Given any two distinct odd primes $p$,$q$ can we find a Carmichael number divisible by $pq$?

Tags: number-theory

Given any two distinct odd primes $p$,$q$ can we find a Carmichael number divisible by $pq$?

If so, given any two distinct odd primes $p$,$q$ can we find a Carmichael number divisible by $pq$, wich have exactly 4 factors?

Comment: What's the question?  Are you, possibly, asking "given any two distinct odd primes $p,q$  can we find a Carmichael number divisible by $pq$?" ?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Suppose $p\,|\,q-1$.  If $n$ is a Carmichael number divisible by $q$ we must have $q-1\,|\,n-1$.  Hence $p$ divides $n-1$, so $p$ can not divide $n$.

Comment: Short and clear, thanks

Comment: And what about, if gcd($p$,$q-1$) = 1 and gcd($q$,$p-1$) = 1

Comment: I don't know.  If you asked me to guess, I'd say that the obstruction I illustrated was the only one...but I am certainly not sure of that and I don't know how to go about constructing such $n$.  So far as I am aware, it isn't even known that there are infinitely many Carmichael numbers divisible by a fixed prime (but, again, I could have that wrong).